# Bucketing for histogram in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

Syntax issue on line #25. Can someone please help me to spot the mistake not sure if the problem is in the code before this line.

File SyntaxError: invalid syntax, line 25

```
} #25
^
```

The line with the syntax is highlighted by #25. Thank you in advance :)

```
import pandas as pd

def length_vs_references(articles):
  
    res = {"1-5" : 0, "6-10" : 0, "11-15" : 0, "16-20" : 0, "21-25" : 0, "25-30" : 0, ">30" :0}
    n = {"1-5" : 0, "6-10" : 0, "11-15" : 0, "16-20" : 0, "21-25" : 0, "25-30" : 0, ">30" :0}
    
    cursor = articles.aggregate([
        {'$match': {'$and' : [{'references': {'$exists': False}
        }, {'$ne':['$page_end', '']}, {'$ne':['$page_start', '']} ]}},
        {'$project': {'len_refernces': {"$size": '$references'},
                                                'pages': {'$subtract': [{"$toInt": 'page_end'},
                                                                        {"$toInt" : 'page_start'}]}}},
        
            {'$bucket' : {
            '$groupBy': '$pages',
            'boundaries': [ 0, 6, 11, 16, 21, 26, 31, 1000000],
                'default': 'Other',
            {
                'output' : {"average": {"$avg" : '$len_references'}},
            }
                        } #25
            }
        
    ])


    return cursor
    
print(length_vs_references(articles))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            'default': 'Other',
        {
            'output' : {"average": {"$avg" : '$len_references'}},
        }
```

That is the problem area.  You have a sub-dictionary without a key name.

To illustrate the problem more simply, here is an equivalent dictionary:

```
mydict = {
    'some_key': 5,
    'other_key': 10,
    'yet_another_key': 100,
    3,
    'final_key': 1000
}
```

The `3` is an error because it's just a value without a key name.  Your code has a sub-dictionary instead of an integer, but it's the same kind of error.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry I have only just started coding. What do you mean by sub-dictionary without a key name. Thank you

Comment: At that point in the code, you are inside a dictionary and thus you should be providing key-value pairs such as the first line `'default': 'Other'`.  But the next line is not a key-value pair; it is just a value.  Presumably you meant to assign it a keyname.

Comment: @Saihdev I've updated my answer to illustrate the problem more simply.

Comment: I see thank you. So I have only put a value within this dictionary not a key name. To solve this would I put a key name before the output? e.g 'key':  { 'output' : {"average": {"$avg" : '$len_references'}}

Comment: When I change my code to the above I now receive OperationFailure from --->33 print(length_vs_references(articles)). Any ideas? Thank you :)